# How to perform tap hold on android?

Tags: android, input, monkeyrunner

I'm trying to script a tap and hold on an Android device and I haven't worked out how.

I tried playing with the `input` command options but couldn't find anything relating to holding.

I've also looked at [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyRunner.html) and could succesfully get the desired effect from a computer with the Android device connected, but couldn't run `monkeyrunner` on the device itself, without a computer.

Is there a way to script a tap and hold/tap down only/long tap on an Android device (I'm just using the shell for now) ? If so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to inject events. You can use [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) or Monkeyrunner for testing. Or you can try to inject events directly [this](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/01/programmatically-injecting-events-on-android-part-2/#.UgNn3nciUls) way.

Comment: Awesome! Didn't know about those, thanks (+1). I'll give them a try when I get my hands on a device again and check this.

Comment: FWIW, a similar option that worked for me was performing a swipe on a short area, but with a long duration (e.g. `adb shell input swipe 1100 512 1100 520 60`)